# Accessing operators in Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have the following array in javascript.

```
array = [2, 3, "+"]
```

My goal is to write code that will take the second element of the array (array[1]), perform whatever operator is in element 3 (array[2]) to element 1 (array[0]).

For example the code should be able to do the following.

`[2,3,"+"]` should output 5 (3+2)

`[2,4,"*"]` should output 8 (4*2)

Currently I can write code that will return "3+2" and "4*2" as strings, but it won't perform the operation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use `eval()`, but rather than opening up that can of worms, why don't you use something like...

```
var operators = {
  '+': function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  '*': function(a, b) { return a * b; }
};

var result = operators[array[2]](array[0], array[1]);
```

If you want to use `eval()`, ensure that you confirm that the operands are only numbers and the operator is from a whitelist of valid operators. Particularly if you are using user input.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map of operator and corresponding method and call that method with operands, but if you want a quick and dirty solution just do eval (dangerous is input is from user)

```
> eval('2+3')
 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the code below is easy to implement.

```
var result;
var s;

switch (array[2]) {
    case "+":
        result = array[0] + array[1];
        s = result + "(" + array[0] + " " + array[2] + " " + array[1] + ")";
        break;
    case "-":
        result = array[0] - array[1];
        s = result + "(" + array[0] + " " + array[2] + " " + array[1] + ")";
        break;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute the expression use eval function as below.

```
eval(array[1] + array[2] + array[0]);
```